# How to force type inference without using an abstract class

Tags: scala

I have a factory object that creates instances of some element (that is an inner type). I also have an operation that works on elements created by the factory. Here is the code:

```
class Factory {
  class Element private [Factory] (val int:Int)
  def create(from:Int) = new Element(from)
}

class OperationOnFactoryElement(val factory:Factory) {
  def apply(element:factory.Element) = factory.create(element.int + 1)
}

val factory = new Factory

val op = new OperationOnFactoryElement(factory)

val someElement = factory.create(1)

op(someElement) // this causes an error!!

//<console>:13: error: type mismatch;
// found   : factory.Element
// required: op.factory.Element
//              op(someElement)
//                 ^
```

It is clear that the compiler expects me to use the factory embedded in the `OperationOnFactoryElement` to accept the operation. However, if I need to define more operations on that element, it becomes a problem because I cannot, for example combine the two operations. I came up with this solution:

```
class Factory {
  class Element private [Factory] (val int:Int)
  def create(from:Int) = new Element(from)
}

abstract class OperationOnFactoryElement {
  val factory:Factory
  def apply(element:factory.Element) = factory.create(element.int + 1)
}

val myfactory = new Factory

val op = new OperationOnFactoryElement {
val factory:myfactory.type = myfactory
}
val someElement = myfactory.create(1)

op(someElement) // this works
```

However, I'm forced to turn my operation into an abstract class. My question is:

Is there a way to achieve the same result without making the class `OperationOnFactoryElement` abstract?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Factory#Element` to tell `apply` to expect an `Element` defined within a `Factory`

```
 class OperationOnFactoryElement(val factory:Factory) {
   def apply(element:Factory#Element) = factory.create(element.int + 1)
 }
```

with this change, your first example of code should work as is.

```
scala> class Factory {
     |   class Element private [Factory] (val int:Int)
     |   def create(from:Int) = new Element(from)
     | }
defined class Factory

scala> class OperationOnFactoryElement(val factory:Factory) {
     |    def apply(element:Factory#Element) = factory.create(element.int + 1)
     |  }
defined class OperationOnFactoryElement

scala> val factory = new Factory
factory: Factory = Factory@650b5efb

scala> val op = new OperationOnFactoryElement(factory)
op: OperationOnFactoryElement = OperationOnFactoryElement@33abb81e

scala> val someElement = factory.create(1)
someElement: factory.Element = Factory$Element@bebf1eb

scala> op(someElement)
res0: op.factory.Element = Factory$Element@6176959c

scala> someElement.int
res1: Int = 1

scala> res0.int
res2: Int = 2
```